# Finding my mistakes margin:50px auto;

Tags: css, layout, centering

Hello i need to center the img on that div.. i cant.. :(

Im using margin:Xpx auto; with relative defined with, display:block, what else?

css.

```
  .items div {
      float:left;
      width:380px;
  }

  /* single scrollable item */
  .scrollable img {
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      margin:50px auto;
      margin-bottom:0px;
      padding:2px;
      border:0px solid #ccc;
      max-width:335px;
      display:block;
      width:auto;
  }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="scrollable" id="navigator">
   <div class="items">

    <!-- 1 -->
    <div>
      <img src="images/design/balanza.jpg"  />
      <br clear="left"  />
      <p class="galdescr">Caperucita y la Abuela<br />
Raúl Caudillo<br />
Oil, acrilic, colored pencil and graphite on paper<br />
2010</p>
    </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really center something that is floated. It is either floated to the left or the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing it to inline-block rather than block.
or you use a a static value for width (i.e. `width` instead of `max-width`), you can just set `margin-left` to something that will center it